# Access Denied appxmanifest.xml

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, appxmanifest

I need to programmatically add ContentURIs to package.appxmanifest file for Windows Phone 10 development. I am able to read the appxmanifest.xml file into XDocument, update it but unable to write it back to appxmanifest.xml, as it keeps throwing error "ACCESS DENIED". Can someone please help me, as I need to achieve this programmatically.

Comment: Why a down vote, I required this with my application, till Windows Phone 8 it was supported but not with window phone 10, so can't I ask the same here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it, the file is read only. I suppose it is for security reasons, so the apps do not change their permissions ta runtime, because this could lead to security issues.

Comment: Ohh... But I want my user to configure the CONTENT URI from some custom configuration page, that I provide to him, so that when ScriptNotify event would fire then, my app should be able to handle that, if I cannot programmatically add URI to ApplicationContentUriRules then in what other way can I achieve this? Could you please show me a better way to achieve this?